# Linear Regression fit (augment) on a different dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

I'm simply trying to calculate the prediction (fitted values) on a different dataset the regression model was built on using dplyr and the augment function. However I keep getting errors. Even without using dplyr, the augment function seems to only accept the dataset the model was built on. Any solution to resolve that? Below is one of my attempt. Thank you.

```
data1 <- head(mtcars,20)

model <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(fit = lm(wt ~ mpg, .),
     data = (.)) %>%
  augment(fit, data1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `augment` in `mutate` and use `map` to pass one model at a time in `augment`.

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(fit = lm(wt ~ mpg, .),
     data = (.)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(col   = map(fit, augment, newdata = data1))
```

Also since `do` has been superseded you can fit the model in `summarise`.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(fit = list(lm(wt ~ mpg)), 
            data = list(cur_data())) %>%
  mutate(col   = map(fit, augment, newdata = data1))

#    cyl fit    data               col               
#  <dbl> <list> <list>             <list>            
#1     4 <lm>   <tibble [11 × 11]> <tibble [20 × 14]>
#2     6 <lm>   <tibble [7 × 11]>  <tibble [20 × 14]>
#3     8 <lm>   <tibble [14 × 11]> <tibble [20 × 14]>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's pretty much what I was trying to do. However how can I unnest col? I keep getting an error when doing that.

Comment: That is because you already have `cyl` column in your data which is also present in `col`. You can `select` the columns that you need from `col` and `unnest` them. Change the last `mutate` line with `mutate(col   = map(fit, augment, newdata = data1), col = map(col, ~.x %>% select(.fitted,  .resid))) %>% unnest(col)`

Comment: I believe some records get evaluated more that once. The original data has only 11 records with cyl ==4. The resulting table has more than 11 records where cyl==4

Comment: Yes, that is because we are using `data1` in `augment` which has 20 records so you get 20 records for each `cyl` value.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. Would you know of a simple way to keep the data 1 groups together. In other words is there a way to apply the group_by, summarize functions to data1 evaluation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: By that I mean would it be possible to only use data from the same "cyl" groups to do the evaluation? That's what group by and summarize do in the first part with the original dataset. However when evaluating on data1 the evaluation is not kept by group. I would like to be able to do something lik this: "group_by %>%mutate(col   = map(fit, augment, newdata = data1))"

Comment: Regarind `would it be possible to only use data from the same "cyl" groups to do the evaluation` . Which data are you talking about? `data1` is common across all `cyl` value, `lm` which we are applying is specific to `cyl` data hence `fit` is also specific to `cyl` data only.